# I am having a hard time converting this do while logic into a while loop. What would be the logic to covert it?

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I am having a hard time converting this do while logic into a while loop. Can anyone help?

Here, I am just reading the 1st character and checking if it is a space or a EOF. If its a space you add a space. For EOF you do not need to add the space, but I did not want to handle it with another if condition.

If is not eof or a space you add the char in morse buffer and then read the char with a function to morse buffer and the function returns the char decoded which gets appended to word.

The problem is I do not want to have a if condition and then break the loop. I want while(some condition) not while(true)

```
#include "headers/main.h"

/* Global variables */
char morse_buff[MORSE_BUFFER_SIZE];
int morse_buff_idx = 0;
/* local functions */
static char read_morse_return_char(FILE *morse_file, struct hsearch_data *hashtable) {
    int read_char;
    do {
        read_char = fgetc(morse_file);
        if (read_char == ' ' || read_char == '\n') {
            morse_buff[morse_buff_idx] = '\0';
            morse_buff_idx = 0;
            ENTRY item = {.key = morse_buff};
            return morse_char_to_roman_char(hashtable,item);
        } else {
            morse_buff[morse_buff_idx++] = read_char;
        }
        
    }while(true);
}

/* Functions */
void read_morse_display_word(FILE *morse_file, struct hsearch_data *hashtable) {
    /* Ensure that file pointer is not equal to NULL */
    assert("NULL pointer passed as morse file" && morse_file != NULL);
    
    char word[WORD_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int word_idx =0, read_char;
    // possible while
    do {
        read_char = fgetc(morse_file);
        if (read_char == EOF || read_char == ' ') {
            /* There will be an extra space in the word buffer after the the last char that occurs at EOF. 
             * Since the display is terminal it will not matter. Therefore, there is no
             * extra handing for this case during EOF.  
             */
            word[word_idx++] = ' '; /* Append space */
            word[word_idx] = '\0'; /* Append null just to be safe */
            word_idx = 0; /* Reset index to zero */
            printf("%s", word); /* Print the resultant word */
            if(read_char == EOF) {
                break; /* Break at end of file */
            }
            fgetc(morse_file);  /* Read the next space and ignore it */
        } else {
            morse_buff[morse_buff_idx++] = read_char; /* append char in morse_buff */
            word[word_idx++] = read_morse_return_char(morse_file,hashtable); /* append decoded char in word buff */
        }
    }while(true);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Expected Results:
[image]

Source Code: Nothing great.
Link: https://gitlab.com/DirtyVoid/computer_systems/-/tree/main/A4%3AMorseCodeDecoding/MorseCodeDecoder/src

Comment: This is an "endless" loop, what exactly have you tried converting that doesn't work?

Comment: `do {} while(true);` is synonymous to `while(true) {}`. I'm curious what the *real* problem you're trying to fix is.

Comment: The problem is I do not want to have a if condition and then break the loop. I want while(some condition) not while(true)

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: I just want to have less if conditions if at all possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "fiddley", trying to do different manipulations *on-the-fly*, but I believe this implements what the OP code does but without if/else and break confabulations.

This can only be theoretical as the code snippet lacks input, output and data definitions. Cannot test this.

```
static char read_morse_return_char(FILE *morse_file, struct hsearch_data *hashtable) {
    int read_char;

    while( ( read_char = fgetc( morse_file ) ) != ' ' && read_char != '\n' )
        morse_buff[morse_buff_idx++] = read_char;

    morse_buff[morse_buff_idx] = '\0';
    morse_buff_idx = 0;

    ENTRY item = {.key = morse_buff};

    return morse_char_to_roman_char(hashtable,item);
}

void read_morse_display_word(FILE *morse_file, struct hsearch_data *hashtable) {
    assert("NULL pointer passed as morse file" && morse_file != NULL);
    
    char word[WORD_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int word_idx =0, read_char;

    do {
        while( ( read_char = fgetc( morse_file ) ) != ' ' && read_char != EOF ) {
            morse_buff[morse_buff_idx++] = read_char; /* append char in morse_buff */
            word[word_idx++] = read_morse_return_char(morse_file,hashtable); /* append decoded char in word buff */
        }

        word[word_idx++] = ' '; /* Append space */
        word[word_idx] = '\0'; /* Append null just to be safe */
        word_idx = 0; /* Reset index to zero */
        printf("%s", word); /* Print the resultant word */
    } while( read_char != EOF && fgetc(morse_file) != EOF );

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @DirtyV Actually, if the code in this answer works as you want, there's no reason to paste the entire source into the question. I tried to follow the logic flow of the code you posted and revise it to have fewer conditionals and odd 'break' statements... Please just try this code and see if it does what you were hoping to achieve.

Comment: your code also works exactly like mine. Can you explain this condition? `while( read_char != EOF && fgetc(morse_file) != EOF );`

Comment: @DirtyV Your code tested for EOF, then "tossed away" the next character in the stream. The 'extension' of testing that "next character" for EOF is to abandon the input if the "next character" does not exist...

Comment: Sorry, for the late response. I stepped away from my computer for a bit. Yes you got that right it converts morse code dot/dash into plain text. Input text file is morse code where words are separated by 3 spaces. 
`https://gitlab.com/DirtyVoid/computer_systems/-/tree/main/A4%3AMorseCodeDecoding/MorseCodeDecoder/src`
You can find the source code here in case your are curious.
It does not implement the hashtable from scratch because gnu extended <search.h> contains hash-tables.

Comment: Also thanks for teaching me how to change it. After looking at your solution for a while I realized if I just applied compliment to my conditions then I should have been able come up with the same logic. and also really liked this part `while( read_char != EOF && fgetc(morse_file) != EOF );`

Comment: @DirtyV It's "homebrew", but was kinda fun figuring out how to do it "look up table" driven... I'm going to delete most of my recent comments to keep the SO gods happy... Play with my gunk... It's not a finished/polished product... Be kind `:-)`

Comment: I liked your approach. it also led me to the realization that since I am reading char by char. I should also print char by char. and it appears to be more efficient.

Comment: @DirtyV My interest was just mucking about with the forward & reverse "enciphering" and seeing if I could get a scheme to use Morse's 1-6 dots/dashes as a single byte. (I know "error" is 8 bits, but... I don't make errors... (Hahahahaha)... Buffering or not is tangential, imo... stdin & stdout are buffered anyway... "Are we having fun yet??" `:-)`